# Is there a way I can search two JSON files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently, I'm working on a project that searches through two different JSON files.
Right now, I have:

```js
var search = message.content
 .split(/\s+/g)
 .slice(1)
 .join(' ');
if (!search) return message.reply('Please give a character name!');

var waifuobj = waifusearch; //My JSON file
var husbandoobj = husbandosearch; //My other JSON file

let WName = Object.values(waifuobj.waifuID).find(
 (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
).names;
let HName = Object.values(husbandoobj.husbandoID).find(
 (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
).names;

let WImg = Object.values(waifuobj.waifuID).find(
 (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
).img_url;
let HImg = Object.values(husbandoobj.husbandoID).find(
 (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
).img_url;

let WClaim = Object.values(waifuobj.waifuID).find(
 (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
).claims;
let HClaim = Object.values(husbandoobj.husbandoID).find(
 (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
).claims;

let embed = new MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle(`${WName}`)
 .setDescription(`Claims: ${WClaim}`)
 .setImage(`${WImg}`)
 .setColor('#f095d1')
 .setFooter(
  `Powered by: Twintails API `,
  `https://64.media.tumblr.com/1a1c3bcc08b5a048b90139a56fe7f415/tumblr_o9ku1rVS8z1vnqjx7o2_250.png`
 );

message.channel.send(embed);
```

I want it so that it searches both JSON files. This code right now searches through the waifusearch JSON and finds all the waifu names, img_url's and claims. I want it, so if a person searches a husbando name, it looks through the husbandosearch JSON file instead of the waifusearch one.

Example of waifuID & husbandoID:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a variable that knows if the person searched for a husbando or waifu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put both objects in an array, and use the [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function.

```js
// array of both objects
var data = [waifuobj, husbandoobj];

// try this:
const { names, claims, img_url } = Object.values(
  Object.values(
    data.find((obj) =>
      Object.values(Object.values(obj)[0]).find(
        (value) => value.names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()
      )
    )
  )[0]
)[0];
```

---

Edit: I found a much more compact way using the [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

```js
const data = [waifuobj, husbandoobj];

const { names, claims, img_url } = data
  .reduce((a, v) => a.concat(Object.values(Object.values(v)).flat()), [])
  .find(({ names }) => names.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: husbandoID/waifuID is https://prnt.sc/ud8edv, https://prnt.sc/ud8eqk

Comment: What _exactly_ should I do?

Comment: Without changing it to id?

Comment: I edited my answer so that it's much more efficient, and you won't have to change anything. Please try it when you have the chance.

Comment: Glad I could help! All of those `Object.values()` in one function is nauseating :p

Comment: @HK420 I know this is very *very* late, but I made a much more compact method and edited my answer. Hope you like it!